# plotting two vectors of data on a GGPLOT2 scatter plot using R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I've been experimenting with both `ggplot2` and `lattice` to graph panels of data. I'm having a little trouble wrapping my mind around the `ggplot2` model. In particular, how do I plot a scatter plot with two sets of data on each panel:

in `lattice` I could do this:

```
xyplot(Predicted_value + Actual_value ~ x_value | State_CD, data=dd)
```

and that would give me a panel for each State_CD with each column

I can do one column with `ggplot2`:

```
pg <- ggplot(dd, aes(x_value, Predicted_value)) + geom_point(shape = 2) 
      + facet_wrap(~ State_CD) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)
print(pg)
```

What I can't grok is how to add Actual_value to the ggplot above.

**EDIT** Hadley pointed out that this really would be easier with a reproducible example. Here's code that seems to work. Is there a better or more concise way to do this with ggplot? Why is the syntax for adding another set of points to ggplot so different from adding the first set of data?

```
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)

#make some example data
dd<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(108),36,3),c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),rep("C",24)))
colnames(dd) <- c("Predicted_value", "Actual_value", "x_value", "State_CD")

#plot with lattice
xyplot(Predicted_value + Actual_value ~ x_value | State_CD, data=dd)

#plot with ggplot
pg <- ggplot(dd, aes(x_value, Predicted_value)) + geom_point(shape = 2) + facet_wrap(~ State_CD) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)
print(pg)

pg + geom_point(data=dd,aes(x_value, Actual_value,group=State_CD), colour="green")
```

The lattice output looks like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cerebralmastication.com](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/lattice.png))</sub>

and ggplot looks like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cerebralmastication.com](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/ggplot.png))</sub>

Comment: It would be much easier to offer suggestions if you supplied a reproducible example

Comment: yeah, that's a good point. It was lazy of me to not create a full example. I'll try to work some up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just following up on what Ian suggested: for ggplot2 you really want all the y-axis stuff in one column with another column as a factor indicating how you want to decorate it.  It is easy to do this with `melt`.  To wit:

```
qplot(x_value, value, 
      data = melt(dd, measure.vars=c("Predicted_value", "Actual_value")), 
      colour=variable) + facet_wrap(~State_CD)
```

Here's what it looks like for me:
[image]
<sub>(source: [princeton.edu](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jcone/example.png))</sub>

To get an idea of what `melt` is actually doing, here's the head:

```
> head(melt(dd, measure.vars=c("Predicted_value", "Actual_value")))
     x_value State_CD        variable      value
1  1.2898779        A Predicted_value  1.0913712
2  0.1077710        A Predicted_value -2.2337188
3 -0.9430190        A Predicted_value  1.1409515
4  0.3698614        A Predicted_value -1.8260033
5 -0.3949606        A Predicted_value -0.3102753
6 -0.1275037        A Predicted_value -1.2945864
```

You see, it "melts" Predicted_value and Actual_value into one column called `value` and adds another column called `variable` letting you know what column it originally came from.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: several years on now, I almost always use Jonathan's method (via the [tidyr package](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/)) with ggplot2. My answer below works in a pinch, but gets tedious fast when you have 3+ variables.

---

I'm sure Hadley will have a better answer, but - the syntax is different because the `ggplot(dd,aes())` syntax is (I think) primarily intended for plotting just one variable.  For two, I would use:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dd, aes(x_value, Actual_value, group=State_CD), colour="green") + 
geom_point(data=dd, aes(x_value, Predicted_value, group=State_CD), shape = 2) + 
facet_wrap(~ State_CD) + 
theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Pulling the first set of points out of the ggplot() gives it the same syntax as the second.  I find this easier to deal with because the syntax is the same and it emphasizes the "Grammar of Graphics" that is at the core of ggplot2.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Indeed! `aspect.ratio` is now in the `theme()` function. Answer updated - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

you might just want to change the form of your data a little bit, so that you have one y-axis variable, with an additional factor variable indicating whether it is a predicted or actual variable.

Is this something like what you are trying to do?

```
dd<-data.frame(type=rep(c("Predicted_value","Actual_value"),20),y_value=rnorm(40),
                x_value=rnorm(40),State_CD=rnorm(40)>0)
qplot(x_value,y_value,data=dd,colour=type,facets=.~State_CD)
```

Comment: ahhh.. I think that's what the examples in the ggplot docs are doing. That certainly helps my thinking

Answer (score 1):

well after posting the question I ran across [this R Help thread](http://www.nabble.com/A-beginner%27s-question-about-ggplot-td23336793.html) that may have helped me. It looks like I can do this:

```
 pg + geom_line(data=dd,aes(x_value, Actual_value,group=State_CD), colour="green")
```

is that a good way of doing things? It odd to me because adding the second item has a totally different syntax than the first.

Comment: Note that you only have to change things from the defaults that you set in the ggplot() part. In your case you only have to set the new y-value and the colour.

ggplot(dd, aes(x= x_value, y = Predicted_value)) + geom_point(shape = 2) + facet_wrap(~ State_CD) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1) + geom_line(aes(yActual_value, colour="green")