# Colouring ggplot's plotmatrix by k-means clusters?

Tags: r, ggplot2, k-means

I am trying to create a pairs plot of 6 data variables using ggplot2 and colour the points according to the k-means cluster they belong to. I read the documentation of the highly impressive 'GGally' package as well as an informal fix by Adam Laiacano [http://adamlaiacano.tumblr.com/post/13501402316/colored-plotmatrix-in-ggplot2]. Unfortunately, I could not find any way to get the desired output in either.

Here is a sample code:-

```
#The Swiss fertility dataset has been used here

data_ <- read.csv("/home/tejaskale/Ubuntu\ One/IUCAA/Datasets/swiss.csv", header=TRUE)
data_ <- na.omit(data_)

u <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
x <- data_[,u]
k <- 3
maxIterations <- 100
noOfStarts <- 100
filename <- 'swiss.csv'

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(GGally)

kmeansOutput <- kmeans(x, k, maxIterations, noOfStarts)

xNew <- cbind(x[,1:6], as.factor(kmeansOutput$cluster))
names(xNew)[7] <- 'cluster'
kmeansPlot <- ggpairs(xNew[,1:6], color=xNew$cluster)

OR

kmeansPlot <- plotmatrix(xNew[,1:6], mapping=aes(colour=xNew$cluster))
```

Both plots are created but aren't coloured according to clusters.

Hope I haven't missed an answer to this question on the forum and apologize if that is indeed the case. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that with the normal plot command as well by passing the clusterIDs in the `col` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @ThomasJungblut. But I am not sure I completely understand it. Are you advising the use of facets? I tried playing with facet_grid using examples given on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313954/plotting-two-vectors-of-data-on-a-ggplot2-scatter-plot-using-r. They are not serving my purpose though. A minimal example would be of immense help for me to better understand your suggestion. Thanks once again!

Comment: It is just a normal scatter plot of your points colored by the clusters. See the normal kmeans doc here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html down at the bottom: `plot(x, col = cl$cluster)` where `cl$cluster` is the assignment to a cluster.

Comment: Okay, understood what you meant. But I am looking to generate this plot using 'ggplot2' and I don't think I can substitute 'plot' with 'qplot' here. Any idea how do I go about this using 'ggplot2'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following slight modification of `plotmatrix2` works fine for me:

```
plotmatrix2 <- function (data, mapping = aes())
{
    grid <- expand.grid(x = 1:ncol(data), y = 1:ncol(data))
    grid <- subset(grid, x != y)
    all <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(grid), function(i) {
        xcol <- grid[i, "x"]
        ycol <- grid[i, "y"]
        data.frame(xvar = names(data)[ycol], yvar = names(data)[xcol], 
            x = data[, xcol], y = data[, ycol], data)
    }))
    all$xvar <- factor(all$xvar, levels = names(data))
    all$yvar <- factor(all$yvar, levels = names(data))
    densities <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:ncol(data), function(i) {
        data.frame(xvar = names(data)[i], yvar = names(data)[i], 
            x = data[, i])
    }))
    densities$xvar <- factor(densities$xvar, levels = names(data))
    densities$yvar <- factor(densities$yvar, levels = names(data))
    mapping <- defaults(mapping, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y"))
    class(mapping) <- "uneval"
    ggplot(all) + facet_grid(xvar ~ yvar, scales = "free") + 
        geom_point(mapping, na.rm = TRUE) + stat_density(aes(x = x, 
        y = ..scaled.. * diff(range(x)) + min(x)), data = densities, 
        position = "identity", colour = "grey20", geom = "line")
}


plotmatrix2(mtcars[,1:3],aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

It may be a **ggplot2** version issue, but I had to force the faceting variables in the `densities` data frame to be factors (that seems broken to me even in the **GGally** version). Also, generally don't pass vectors to `aes()`, but simply column names.

Comment: this worked for me though still trying to understand the functioning of the code from 'defaults' onwards. also, thanks for the tip regarding 'aes()'.

Comment: With the most recent ggplot2 version (iirc 0.9.3.1), this produces `could not find function "defaults"`.