# scatterplotMatrix with group histograms

Tags: r, plot, histogram

It's pretty easy to build a nice huge scatterplot matrix with histograms down the diagonal for multivariate data as follows:

```
scatterplotMatrix(somedata[1:points.count,],groups=somedata[1:points.count,class],
                by.groups=TRUE,diagonal="histogram")
```

According to the documentation though, it doesn't seem possible to divide up the histogram by the group labels as is done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370460/scatterplot-with-alpha-transparent-histograms-in-r?lq=1). How would you do that using scatterplotMatrix or a similar function?

Comment: Check out ```GGally``` package for the function ```ggpairs()```. [This question has an interesting solution also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503902/colouring-ggplots-plotmatrix-by-k-means-clusters). Look for the answer with the plotmatrix2 function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

Using the iris dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)  # for melt(...)
library(plyr)      # for .(...)

xx <- with(iris, data.table(id=1:nrow(iris), group=Species, 
           Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
# reshape for facetting with ggplot
yy <- melt(xx,id=1:2, variable.name="H", value.name="xval")
yy <- data.table(yy,key="id,group")
ww <- yy[,list(V=H,yval=xval),key="id,group"]
zz <- yy[ww,allow.cartesian=T]
setkey(zz,H,V,group)
zz <- zz[,list(id, group, xval, yval, min.x=min(xval), min.y=min(yval),
               range.x=diff(range(xval)),range.y=diff(range(yval))),by="H,V"]
# points colored by group (=species)
# density plots for each variable by group
d  <-  zz[H==V, list(x=density(xval)$x,
          y=mean(min.y)+mean(range.y)*density(xval)$y/max(density(xval)$y)),
          by="H,V,group"]
ggp = ggplot(zz)
ggp = ggp + geom_point(subset  =.(H!=V), 
                       aes(x=xval, y=yval, color=factor(group)), 
                       size=3, alpha=0.5)
ggp = ggp + geom_line(subset = .(H==V), data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(group)))
ggp = ggp + facet_grid(V~H, scales="free")
ggp = ggp + scale_color_discrete(name="Species")
ggp = ggp + labs(x="", y="")
ggp
```

[image]

I keep hearing that the same thing is possible using `ggpairs(...)` in package GGally. I would love to see an actual example of it. The documentation is inscrutable. Also, `ggpairs(...)` is extremely slow (in my hands), especially with large datasets.

Comment: It's beautiful. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I haven't gotten to it yet. My policy is to at least *try* out solutions before I accept, although I upvote on the spot.

Comment: This is pretty hard on memory, huh? With that cartesian product, you get N*(M-1) points (where M is the number of feature types)?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander - N*M^2 actually. This is why data.tables are used for the joins. In practical terms: if you have say 1e5 points and 10 feature types, still only 1e7 rows in `zz`. Consider what this would look like, with a 10 X 10 matrix of tiny facets, each containing 10,000 points.

Answer (score 1):

For later reference, the GGally way to do it is as follows:

```
require(ggpairs)
tmp <- data.table(a = runif(30),b = runif(30), c = runif(30)+1, 
                  d = as.factor(sample(0:1,size=30, replace=TRUE)))

ggpairs(data=tmp, diag=list(continuous="density"), columns=1:3, colour="d",
        axisLabels="show")
```

[image: pairwise scatterplot matrix with group densities on diagonal]

[This intrepid asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079977/ggally-unexpected-behavior-with-ggpairs-diag-list-continuous-densit) figured out that you have to enable axisLabels which is somewhat silly, given the aesthetic emphasis of ggplot and friends.

Now I want to know how to parallelize this, because it's a monster with high numbers of variables.