# Overlay two plots (ggplot)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How I can overlay the scatter plot of AverageTime2 vs. AverageCost and AverageTime1 vs. AverageCost. (in ggplot)?

```
Type<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
AverageTime<-c(12,14,66,123,14,33,44,55,55,6,66)
AverageTime2<-c(14,15,66,126,14,100,144,55,55,16,90)
AverageCost<-c(100,10000,400,20000,500000,5000,700,800,400000,500,120000)
AverageCost2<-c(10000,10000,4000,20000,5000,50000,7000,8000,40000,50000,120000)
df<-data.frame(Type,AverageTime,AverageTime2,AverageCost,AverageCost2)
```

Comment: Melt your data into long format. Anyone have a good r-faq dupe for this?

Comment: Possible dupe, though it's a more complicated case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1313954/903061

Comment: Two `geom_point` layers. `ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(AverageCost, AverageTime), color = 'red') + geom_point(aes(AverageCost, AverageTime2), color = 'blue')`

Comment: @alistaire, Thanks for your suggestion. How can I have geom_smooth() curve? Also How can I show that the color refers to which variable?

Comment: `+ geom_smooth( ... )`. Legends are more finicky with this approach; it may be easier to reshape your data as the answers below suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build your data like this

```
df<-rbind(data.frame(Type,AverageTime,AT="T1",AverageCost,AverageCost2),
          data.frame(Type,AverageTime=AverageTime2,AT="T2",
                     AverageCost,AverageCost2))
```

and plot it that way

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+geom_point(aes(AverageTime, AverageCost,color=AT))
```

[image]

Comment: @ HubertL, Thanks for your suggestion, But I want to overlap the plot of AverageTime vs. AverageCost and AverageTime2 vs. AverageCost

Comment: @shoorideh OK Edited

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reshape your data so that the AverageTime and AverageCost are each a column, with a separate column (called something like `Type2`) that distinguishes the two types.

You can accomplish this with dplyr, tidyr, and stringr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df_gather <- df %>%
  gather(column, value, -Type) %>%
  mutate(Type2 = str_detect(column, "2"),
         column = str_replace(column, "2", "")) %>%
  spread(column, value)
```

The particularly important part of that is to gather all the "Average" columns into one column, then to distinguish them (using the `Type2` column), and then to spread them back into separate AverageCost and AverageTime columns.

Afterwards, you can simply do:

```
ggplot(df_gather, aes(AverageTime, AverageCost, color = Type2)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I did not get why you use str_detect(column, "2") ?

Comment: @ David Robinson, Also  I want to overlap these two plots (AverageTime vs. AverageCost) and (AverageTime2 vs. AverageCost)